# Details of transactions in SQL SERVER 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, transaction

I need following details:

- Username of the user who initiated the transaction
- Origin of the query  i.e. Whether Query executed in SQL server New
  Query Interface or Transaction due to editing in Table or Via any
  other application.

I know that all the transactions are saved in .ldf file.
Using sql query/other tools i was able to fetch some details but not all the above for all transactions. 
Is there any way to get all the above information for all transactions.

Answer (score 1):

Use [SQL Server Audit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/sql-server-audit-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15), after upgrading to a supported version of SQL Server.  For SQL Server 2008 there's only [SQL Trace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-trace/sql-trace?view=sql-server-ver15).  And in either case there's no way to get this information after the fact.  You have to set something up to capture it.

Comment: ... in addition, there is no safe way to get which application did the modification. This is because it is the app itself that submits the app_name, so it is very easy to spoof this (for instance there's a command-line switch for this in SQLCMD.EXE).